# Type-safe css having no effect on controls tornadofx

Tags: tornadofx

I am trying to follow the guide for type-safe css. Inline styling works but I can seem to get it to work with an a separate stylesheet class. I have tried for every type of control in my program including listviews, buttons, labels, and textfields. No style is applied at all. My button looks like a totally normal button with none of the borders or rotation.

I stripped down my program to be only one button and the exact code from the guide in my stylesheet class.

My main view, stylesheet, and app.

```java
import tornadofx.*
import com.lordxarus.subtitler.app.MyStyles

class MainView : View("Subtitler!") {
    override val root = vbox {
        button("TEST") {
            addClass(MyStyles.tackyButton)
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class MyStyles : Stylesheet() {

    companion object {
        val tackyButton by cssclass()

        private val topColor = Color.RED
        private val rightColor = Color.DARKGREEN
        private val leftColor = Color.ORANGE
        private val bottomColor = Color.PURPLE
    }


    init {
        tackyButton {
            rotate = 10.deg
            borderColor += box(topColor,rightColor,bottomColor,leftColor)
            fontFamily = "Comic Sans MS"
            fontSize = 20.px
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class Subtitler: App(MainView::class, MyStyles::class)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine, so my guess would be that you're using the TornadoFX IDEA plugin and accidentally ran the View instead of running the App class. The plugin allows you to run views without even defining an app class, but when you do that the framework has no way of knowing that you want to load the stylesheet specified in your app class. Run the `Subtitler` class instead and you'll see your styles applied :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out, I figured it was something stupid like that. Works like a charm

Comment: My pleasure :))